# c++ pointer to function and void pointers iteraction resulting in wierd things

Tags: c++, struct, function-pointers, void-pointers

Im making a little project at home about genetic algorithm. But im trying to make it generic, so i use pointers to function and void pointers. but i think it might be making some problems.

The main goal of this section of the project is to get a pointer to a function, which return a certain struct. The struct containing a void pointer
and when im trying to view the value of where it points too it isn`t quite right.I suspect that maybe the interaction between these two might be causing me some problems.

details:

struct:

```
struct  dna_s{
    int         size;
    void        *dna;
};
```

population is a class contaning all the population for the process. besides, it contains 2 functions as well, init_func and fitter_func which are both pointers to functions.

pointer to function definition:

```
typedef dna_s   (*init_func_t)();
typedef int     (*fitter_func_t)(dna_s);
```

population class:

```
class   population{
    private:
        //  Parameters
        int         population_size;
        node        *pop_nodes;

        //  Functions
        init_func_t     init_func;
        fitter_func_t   fitter_func;
    public:
        population(int  pop_size,init_func_t initialization_func){
            //  Insert parameters into vars.
            this->population_size   = pop_size;
            this->init_func         = initialization_func;

            //  Create new node array.
            this->pop_nodes         = new node[this->population_size];

            for(int i = 0;i < this->population_size; i++){
                dna_s   curr_dna        = this->init_func();
                char *s                = static_cast<char*>(curr_dna.dna);
                cout << s << endl;
                this->pop_nodes[i].update_dna(curr_dna);
            }
        }
};
```

You can see that in the constructor im inserting a pointer to function, init_func. this function is generating random words.

init_func:

```
dna_s   init_func(){
    string alphanum = "0123456789!@#$%^&*ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char        init_s[STRING_SIZE+1]   = {};
    dna_s       dna;

    //  Generate String
    for(int i = 0; i < STRING_SIZE; i++){
        init_s[i]   = alphanum[rand() % alphanum.size()];
    }

    cout    << "-->" << init_s << endl;

    //  Insert into struct.
    dna.size        = STRING_SIZE;
    dna.dna         = static_cast<void*>(&init_s);

    //  Return it
    return dna;
}
```

the main function is not so interesting but it might be connected:

```
int main(){
    //  Init srand
    srand(time(0));

    //  Parameters
    int         population_size     = 10;
    population  pop(population_size, init_func);
}
```

now for the interesting part, whats the problem?
in the init_func the cout prints:

```
-->e%wfF
```

which is all good
but in the population class the cout prints:

```
e%Ω²(
```

and the wierd thing is the first 2 characters will always be the same, but the other 3 will always be this string Ω²(.
example:

```
-->XaYN7
XaΩ²(
-->oBK9Q
oBΩ²(
-->lf!KF
lfΩ²(
-->RZqMm
RZΩ²(
-->oNhMC
oNΩ²(
-->EGB6m
EGΩ²(
-->osafQ
osΩ²(
-->3#NQt
3#Ω²(
-->D62l0
D6Ω²(
-->tV@mu
tVΩ²(
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using pointers (in this way specific and at all)? C++11 introduced `std::function` which is easier and safer to use than what you are trying to do and I really don't understand why you are using `void*` in your struct

Comment: It doesn't need a real answer. Your problem is you're returning a pointer to a variable on the stack which then gets overwritten by something else. You need to allocate a buffer on heap, using new char[] or better yet just use a general container such as std::vector to hold the binary data.

Comment: @UnholySheep `std::function` is a fat type that does much more than you usually need, at a cost. It's not a great default

Comment: @tyranid You`re right i didnt thought of it thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few lifetime issues. In your dna_S struct:

```
    void        *dna;
```

This is a *pointer*, it points to an object that exists elsewhere. Then, in your init_func:

```
dna_s   init_func(){
    ...
    char        init_s[STRING_SIZE+1]   = {};
    dna_s       dna;
    ...
    dna.dna         = static_cast<void*>(&init_s);
    ...
    return dna;
}
```

`init_s` is a variable that exists inside `init_func`, you make `dna` point to that variable and then leave the function. `init_s` ceases to exist at this point, `dna` is pointing nowhere useful when the `population` constructor gets it, causing undefined behavior.

You could work around that by allocating memory with `new char[]`, like you did for `pop_nodes`, but you are responsible for deleting that memory when it is no longer used.